# store touchesMoved value to NSArray in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i want store my touchesMoved value in to NSArray how can i store that. now i try to store my touches moved value but i won't print value.
here is my code

```
- (void)initWithSize:(int)nX height:(int)nY {
    xWidth = nX;
    yHeight = nY;

        xArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:xWidth];

        for (int i = 0; i < xWidth; i++) {

            yArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:yHeight];

            for (int j = 0; j < yHeight; j++) {                

            }

            roomArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:yArray];
            [xArray addObject:roomArray];
            [roomArray release];
            [yArray release];


        }
```

i call this method like this

```
    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    [self initWithSize:currentPoint.x height:currentPoint.y];

}
```

i print this value like this

```
   - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {   

        NSString *myArrayString = [xArray description];
          NSLog(@"screeX:%@ ",xArray);    
    }
```

but i did't get that pixels in my console output 
i got output like this

```
screeX:(
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
```

Comment: as per ur code the array is allocating each time whwn touch is moved...

Comment: @vishy tell me what can i do for storing that value in to array ?

Comment: try the below answer, and let me know the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are implement is not proper.

1. Declare a `NSMutableArray` object in .h file.

   ```
   NSMutableArray *_array;
   ```
2. You can allocate the array in `viewDidLoad`.

   ```
   _array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   ```
3. In `touchesBegin`, remove all the objects of the array.

   ```
   [_array removeAllObjects];
   ```
4. In `touchesMoved`, add the `CGPoint`s to the array as follows.

   ```
   [_array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: currentPoint]];
   ```

Now , in `touchesEnded`, print the array and see the values.

Comment: thank you for your answer i done all the steps but i got out put like this screeX:(null)

Comment: I have updated my answer.. Are you sure you hve done like this?

Comment: Also, make sure that your `viewDidLoad` is getting called.. Otherwise, allocate the array in the `init` method of the class.